# Are there any tools for using SASS in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sass

I know with Visual Studio 2010 and up there's a few different options, specifically what I'm familiar with is Web Workbench. But are there *any* options in Visual Studio 2008, or is SASS just not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sass is not supported, and as far as I know there are no packages supporting Sass for VS 2008. Sass itself came around in 2007 and gained popularity after that, so your best bet is going to be upgrading VS or using something like [sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com) to write Sass and paste the compiled CSS into the editor.